# Why does xp_logininfo shows less members for an AD group?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

This question might be stupid, but it has been confusing me for a while...

First, I used `xp_logininfo 'groupA', 'members'` to show members of `GroupA`, as a result, `member1` and `member2` are listed, but `member3` isn't.

Then, I used `xp_logininfo 'member3', 'all'` showing the permission path of `member3`.  As a result, `groupA` is listed as the permission path of `member3`. But why `member3` isn't listed as a member of `groupA` in the first syntax? Did I miss anything here?

Comment: It might be caused by nesting. Are member1 and member2 direct members of groupA? Is member3 a member of some other group that is then a member of groupA?

Comment: What I saw is both 'member1' and 'member2' are users, they are not groups, so i think they should be direct members of GroupA? Also, i didn't see any AD groups belong to 'GroupA' as the result of xp_logininfo 'GroupA', 'members'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alluded in the comments, `xp_logininfo @account_name, 'members'` will only return a list of the next-level members of the group. This is explained in the [SQL Server Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-logininfo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks). The docs also say "If account_name is a domain account, the list is made up of domain users". So if you request info about a domain group, you will only get domain users back, not any nested groups.

Assuming that GroupA is a domain group, the most likely explanation is that member1 and member2 are direct members of GroupA, but member3 is an indirect member through another domain group that is in GroupA.

We've hit this issue in the past, and it is a little annoying! The workaround we ended up with was to do an LDAP query through openquery on ADSI, sort of like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766061/tsql-how-to-get-a-list-of-groups-that-a-user-belongs-to-in-active-directory). This is a lot more overhead though...